# Why do I need Direct Media in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I have a question, Why do I need to enable the Direct media in Asterisk?

Is it just to improve performance ? Hardware Problems ? Or what exactly?

Why shouldn't I let the Asterisk control the connections between clients?

Can you please inform about this feature and why it is important

Answer (score 1):

Let say you are large provider and have 1000 calls.

If you do it directly, you have 1000*64=64Mbits+ of rtp traffic. If you have 2 servers in line you have that 3x time more on your switches etc etc
In same time you are connected to larger provider, who can do all NAT and RTP job for you.

So you can do just SIP packets without RTP.

From other point of view, not all types of NAT support directrtpsetup and directmedia. For thoose clients you may want proxy rtp.

Comment: First thnx, it mens, just for the performance, and less traffic for the server . If I don't have that much of traffics, it won't really come in hand.!!